# How can I dynamically change CSS class names in an Angular application?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I have two CSS class names as follows.

```
.icon_heart{
     color: #bdbdbd;
}

.icon_heart_red{
    color: #a6b7d4;;
}
```

My HTML contains a heart icon.

```
<div class="icon_heart" *ngIf="showheartIcon">
    <ion-icon name="heart" (click)="setWishlistTrue(category.product_id);" class="heart"></ion-icon>
</div>
<div class="icon_heart_red" *ngIf="showheartIconRed">
    <ion-icon name="heart" (click)="setWishlistFalse(category.product_id);" class="heart"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

There are two `div` elements. The heart icon has a **grey** colour until the user clicks it, then it should change to **blue**.

The following block of code is from my TypeScript file; two icons with different colours.

```
  showheartIcon = true;
  showheartIconRed = false;

  setWishlistTrue(id){
    this.showheartIconRed = true;
    this.showheartIcon = false;
  }

  setWishlistFalse(id){
    this.showheartIconRed = false;
    this.showheartIcon = true;
  }
```

### Is it possible to replace the class of the icon, instead of having two of them?

I have seen in [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_classname) that I can add a class to any HTML element.

How can I achieve that in Angular?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change CSS class names using the following options.

**Option 1**

```
<div 
    [class.icon_heart]="!showheartIconRed"
    [class.icon_heart_red]="showheartIconRed">This is an example.</div>
```

**Option 2**

```
<div [ngClass]="showheartIconRed ? 'icon_heart_red' : 'icon_heart'">This is another example.</div>
```

Comment: However if you use ionic2 components (like <ion-textarea>) this two options not work similar - [ngClass] will work differently than [class.xx]

Comment: sorry - i check this again - and they work similar (probably the other problem case different behaviour in my case)

Comment: To place multiple classes: `<div [ngClass]="showheartIconRead ? 'icon_heart_red big' : 'icon_heart small'">`

Comment: Using `[ngClass]="..."` should be pregerred onver `[class]="..."`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following method in addition to the answer above.

```
<div class="{{showheartIconRed ? 'icon_heart_red' : 'icon_heart' }}">
```